# SharePoint PreActionSave with jQuery alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sharepoint

I am trying to check a field and based on the value, show an alert, then proceed to submitting the form. This is meant to act as a reminder, rather than stopping the submission of the form for correction. All examples that I've seen stop submission until the field is corrected.
The current code checks the field, shows the alert super fast, then submits the form.  How can I get alert to show until the ok button is clicked, then submit?

```
<!--DOCTYPE html--><script type="text/javascript">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.5.0/sweet-alert.min.js"></script><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.5.0/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function PreSaveAction(){
//get field value
var status=document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_7183101f_6b09_40bb_99f7_1a82addc5d7c_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice").value;

//check field value
if (status=="Not Started"){
//display pretty alert
swal("Here's a message!", "It's pretty, isn't it?");
//submit form
return true;
} else {
//submit form if status not right
return true;
}
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the reminder just before the button gets clicked, you can listen for the `mouseenter` event.

```
$("input:submit, button:submit").mouseenter(function(){
        swal("Here's a message!", "It's pretty, isn't it?");
        //Or alert("message");
});

// submit form
```